# Typescript - replace null value with empty string. "undefined is not assignable to type string"

Tags: javascript, typescript

Essentially I have props *initialValues* (formik), if any of the values are null than replace them with an empty string. Here is my interface:

```
export interface random {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  user: {
    fullName: string;
  };
}
```

Then in a useEffect I have:

```
Object.keys(initialValues).forEach(k => {
      initialValues[k as keyof random] = initialValues[k as keyof random] === null ? '' : initialValues[k as keyof random];
    });
```

Which works, but I get this typescript error, and can't figure out where the "undefined" is coming from. My guess is because **user** is a nested object?

```
Type 'string | { fullName: string; } | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string & { fullName: string; }'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string & { fullName: string; }'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Comment: What happens if `user` is null?

Comment: user would at least have the key fullName, which could be null

Comment: What's a "useEffect"? Is this a react-specific question? If so then you might want to tag it as such.

Comment: It is conventional to name interfaces in UpperPascalCase, so please consider changing your interface name from `random` to `Random`.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the code here to be a self-contained [mre] someone can paste into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue.  Right now `initialValues` isn't defined so I'd have to define it myself and risk getting it wrong.  If you make it easier for people to play around with the code in an IDE, you increase the chance of getting a useful answer. If you do decide to modify this and want me to take another look, pls mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me.  Good luck!

Comment: One more thing: do you want your approach to work for an arbitrary interface with arbitrarily nested `string | null` values?  Or do you really only care about `Random`?  If it's the former then you need something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8xqAw).  If it's the latter then I'd say just do each property manually like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nl2oxW).  Let me know how you want me to proceed if at all (and mention @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz I've updated the sandbox, hopefully that makes sense. Edit: it's your first sandbox, unsure how to shorten the URL link

Comment: What "sandbox" are you talking about? Any code you provide should be [edit]ed into the question as plain text.  A link to an external site would be a nice supplement (not that I see one from you) but isn't sufficient by itself to be a [mre].  Let me know when/if that happens (via @jcalz mention)

Comment: The first typescript lang sandbox you posted. How can I post the shortened URL? @jcalz

Comment: You don't have to shorten anything because you can [edit] your question and put the link in there, alongside the plaintext version which also needs to be in there.  There is a TypeScript Playground URL Shortener at https://tsplay.dev which you can use to put TS Playground links in comments, but your [mre] belongs in the question itself and not just in a comment.